# How to override/force the mime type of an image with only html?

Tags: html, html-sanitizing

I have an image file with a png extension and where the mime type returned by the http server is the one for png. However, the image is an svg image and all browsers interpret it as png.
I don't manage the server and I can only upload files with a png extension.

How I can override the mime type returned by the server? I tried the both the`content`and`type`attribute with`image/svg+xml` but it changed nothing. JavaScript is stripped.

Comment: you can't. there's nothing you can do in html to mark a link as a particular mime type, since the mime type is set via a `Content-type` header issued by the SERVER when the resource is retrieved.

Comment: @MarcB hey but there is an`header`attribute in html. However, I can’t find how to use it. Also ie is able to detect the right file type if I open the url directly.

Comment: you mean `<meta http-equiv=...`? that only sets headers for the page the meta tag is in. it can't/won't apply to any pages you click over to from the meta'd page.

Comment: @MarcB no I saw the sanitizer have`header=`in the html attribute whitelist.

Comment: that's for table cells, nothing to do with links.you could try `<a href="foo.png" type="image/svg+xml">`, but the type attribute is supposed to be strictly advisory, and shouldn't affect how the browser treats the linked content.

Comment: @MarcB If you read my question you can see I already tried it. Only presto based browser detect the mime type correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an `<object>` tag instead of `<img>`?

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="image.png"></object>
```

Comment: Only img tags and div with tables are allowed. However the set of allowed attributes is quite wide.